# pst-plot: overfull \hbox when using \psaxes

Tags: pstricks, warnings, pst-plot

Consider the following example, taken from page 8 of the [`pst-plot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.4,-0.5)(12,5)
\psaxes[Dx=100,dx=1,Dy=0.00075,dy=1]{->}(0,0)(12,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
\psplot[linecolor=red, plotstyle=curve,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=200]{0}{11}%
[/const1 3.3 10 8 neg exp mul def /s 10 def
 /const2 6.04 10 6 neg exp mul def ] % optional PS commands
{const1 x 100 mul dup mul mul Euler const2 neg x 100 mul dup mul mul exp mul 2000 mul}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, LaTeX throws the warning

```
Overfull \hbox (312.98018pt too wide) detected at line 9
```

at me.

Can anyone tell me how I get rid of this warning? (I think it might has something to do with `\psaxes` but I'm not sure at all.)

P.S. It occures in other PSTricks plots, too. I can't remember seeing these warnings before when I've first created some (now) old documents, so I have a feeling that a "bug" has been introduced in a recent version of one of the PSTricks packages but I'm not sure.

Comment: No such warning at my end.

Comment: @AlexG I have a fully updated TeX Live 2017 distribution. And you?

Comment: No, I tested on ShareLaTeX, which is definitely not. The size of the TeX box is entirely defined by the `pspicture` dimensions. Maybe there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Okay. I case you have a fully updated TeX Live 2017, can I then make you try the example there?

Comment: Tomorrow I will do.

Comment: sharelatex uses TL2014!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the document class option `draft` and you'll see that the overfull box is marked for the x-axis labels. The reason is that the labels are set on TeX level in a box of width 0pt. So every x axis with labels gets this warning which doesn't hurt.

Comment: No, I'll fix only _real_  bugs. That area is really complecated: fixing one bug and creating a new one is possible here ... ;-)  However, if someone comes with a fix, I'll think about it.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the labels at the ticks. Use `labels=y` and the warning doesn't happen.

Comment: You can try pst-plot.tex from http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-plot/

Comment: There are so many special cases where this part of the code is used and I am not sure if it breaks something other. However, let's see what will be.

Comment: Hi Herbert. Sorry but I'm not sure if you will upload it to CTAN or not. Can you be a bit more specific? `:-)`

Comment: I will wait some time to see if there maybe a new problem with this code change.

Comment: Hi again, Herbert. Has anyone reported any incompatibilities with the new version of `pst-plot`? If not, can I then make you upload it to CTAN?

Comment: Yes, there were some problems. I revert the changes.

Comment: Try version 1.85 of pst-plot.tex: http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-plot/

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, Herbert. (I assume it will be on CTAN soon...)